# May have found a SCRAPER

Tags: discussion

So, during my daring adventures searching through Google to the answer to a user's question, I found their question. But their question was not on this site (Ask Ubuntu). It was (is) on a site called `tech forums`. Here's the address:

`http://software.techforums.space/software/ubuntu-cannot-pair-with-bluetooth-keyboard-db17f616.html`
(It has a link back to the original question.)

My immediate thought was that it must be an illegal SCRAPER, but then I remembered I'm pretty sick and my brain isn't quite working. I can vaguely remember the requirements for SE SCRAPERS, and I could easily research them, but my brain seems to be non-functional when it comes to comparisons (and I hope *not* when it comes to coherency in this question).

So, can anyone tell me if this site is doing what it should be? Is there maybe a report that needs to happen?

Comment: yeah they need to give the author's name... 50% there

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do/200178#200178